# Outlook: How do I configure multiple sources to dump incoming messages to a central Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Given:

- A Gmail account.
- A Hotmail account.
- Multiple RSS feeds.

How do I configure Outlook to dump all incoming messages into the central Inbox folder?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Account Settings, "Data Files" tab, create a new PST called "All Mail"

Click the "Set as Default" button, now, all mail will be aggregated once you restart outlook.

You can probably merge the current mailboxes into it to get started, when you got it, you can remove the old ost/pst's..